# Scipy.optimization linear function approximation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, approximation

I've looked at for function approximation methods in [`scipy.optimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) and after reading description for functions figured out(maybe wrong) that they approximate  non-linear functions only.

For instance if I've sample output after `zip()` function for `x` and `y`

```
[(1,1),(4,2),(6,4),(8,6),(10,11)]
```

As you can see, non-linear function approximates much better but I need linear for my purposes.

I admit the possibility that missed something in documentation of functions presented, so my apologize if question can be answered in the "read docs" way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `np.polyfit` and `scipy.stats.linregress` as suggested by @user2589273, a low-level way to do linear regression is to solve for the matrix of coefficients using `np.linalg.lstsq`. Although this approach is a bit more work than using one of the pre-packaged functions for doing linear regression, it's very useful to understand how this works at a basic level, in particular when you start dealing with multivariate data.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

# a simple linear relationship: y = mx + c with m=0.5 and c=2
x = np.arange(50)
y = x * 0.5 + 2
y += np.random.randn(50) * 5    # add some noise

# we can rewrite the line equation as y = Ap, where A=[[x, 1]] and p=[[m], [c]]
A = np.c_[x, np.ones(50)]

# solving for p gives us the slope and intercept
p, residuals, rank, svals = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)
```

Plotting the fit:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.plot(x, y, 'ob', label='data')
ax.plot(x, A.dot(p), '-k', lw=2, label='linear fit')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for reply. Didn't got how to determine slope `a`(for `ax+b` form) from matrix `A`(if I got it correclty from docs). Or numpy will deal with that for me?

Comment: in this case, `p` would be a size `(2,)` array containing `[gradient, intercept]`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something that does a least squares fit?
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html
Also If I remember correctly, numpy's polyfit had an option to determine the degrees of freedom of the fit you needed, where in your case it would be one.

```
importing polyfit from numpy... etc.

coefficients = polyfit( xlist, ylist, 1 ) #where 1 is the degree of freedom
p = poly1d( coefficients ) 
x = linspace( 0, 5, 100 ) #generates 100 points between 0 and 5 to plot 'curve'
plot( x, p(x), label='Best Fit Line' )
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'll have a look and will come back with result